# Program generation produce error information

Tags: java, angular, jhipster

I am performing jhipster program generation and always notice the following. It seems like there is something wrong. But in the end, the system will say that the generation is done successfully.
Does anyone able to provide me some information, why I got the events.js:183 happened?
thanks beforehand.

```
[12:06:22] I/file_manager - creating folder C:\Projects\jhipster\e-commerce-app\online-store\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
[12:06:22] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Projects\jhipster\e-commerce-app\online-store\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[12:06:22] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Projects\jhipster\e-commerce-app\online-store\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:622:25)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! store@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT postinstall: `node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the store@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT postinstall script.
```

Please note, the .yo=rc.json file is as follows:

```
> {   "generator-jhipster": {
>     "promptValues": {
>       "packageName": "com.mycompany.store",
>       "nativeLanguage": "en"
>     },
>     "jhipsterVersion": "6.6.0",
>     "applicationType": "monolith",
>     "baseName": "store",
>     "packageName": "com.mycompany.store",
>     "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/store",
>     "serverPort": "8080",
>     "authenticationType": "jwt",
>     "cacheProvider": "hazelcast",
>     "enableHibernateCache": true,
>     "websocket": "spring-websocket",
>     "databaseType": "sql",
>     "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
>     "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
>     "searchEngine": false,
>     "messageBroker": false,
>     "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
>     "buildTool": "gradle",
>     "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
>     "jwtSecretKey": "ZjU3YmZjMTRlMTE1YWZjYzUwYzMzMzhmNmU2YTFmZjU5YzQyZTIyMTFjN2IxNmI1NDlhZDZjYWEyZTU0MTRhNDYyMzljZjhkODNlMmYzYTYzMTMwZmMzYWQ4NWIyOTE1YjUwNGMwZGZiYTY5MmE4ZmExN2Q0ZDQyOWMxNjJlZmM=",
>     "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
>     "useSass": true,
>     "clientPackageManager": "npm",
>     "clientFramework": "angularX",
>     "clientTheme": "none",
>     "clientThemeVariant": "",
>     "creationTimestamp": 1580484241176,
>     "testFrameworks": ["protractor"],
>     "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
>     "entitySuffix": "",
>     "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
>     "otherModules": [],
>     "enableTranslation": true,
>     "nativeLanguage": "en",
>     "languages": ["en", "in"],
>     "blueprints": []
```

} }

Comment: Are you using the latest node lts? Did you try again (`npm install -f`) after deleting your project-local node_modules folder? There are some errors with 12.x versions of webdriver-manager used by protractor with Chrome >= 74.

Comment: Thanks Jochen, It is such a simple solution and it work. I reinstall node of the latest version and it doesn't show any error anymore.